# Selling Deep In The Money Put To Cover A Short Stock Position

Tags: options

I was just assigned on some naked RCL call options resulting in a short stock position and I am concerned that the stock could rise quickly.  Rather than lock in the losses, I was thinking of selling very deep in the money put options to protect myself against a quick upswing while enabling a small profit if the stock stays below the put strike.

Details include:

Stock assigned at $40.

Current stock price is $40.22, but could move higher when markets re-open.

Selling a $60 Put expiring in a week could generate a $21 premium depending what happens when markets re-open.

Does this strategy make sense?  Should I choose an even higher strike tomoffer more upside protection?

I would be happy just making a few bucks or breaking even just to get out of this short position.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cost basis of the short stock is $40.

Selling the $60 put for $21 obligates you to buy the stock at $60.   It's a covered put but in term of risk, you're uncovered above $61.

The P&L is:

- Maximum profit at expiration is $1 if RCL is under $60 at expiration unless you are assigned early, which is a good thing.
- Break even is $61
- Losses begin above $61 and you lose dollar for dollar per point of up move

On an expiration basis this doesn't seem like a bad position if you believe that RCL won't rise 20 points.

- Potential problem before expiration?

If RCL rises sharply before expiration, the put's delta will decrease and your position will increasingly lose money.  It's no big deal in the $40's but in the $50's, it starts to rack up.

You can do guesstimations based on current and future delta but because delta isn't linear, it's just a loose approximation.  A good charting program would provide a clear analysis of the what ifs at different times and  prices of RCL.  An even better one would allow you to vary the IV.  Since I can't graph this for you,  here are some random  guesstimates:

Let's assume that  this is a two week put.  The put's delta is about 80+ (position delta is -20). Assume that IV remains unchanged.   A week from now at $53, you're down $200.  A week from now at $60, you're down $500.  Not looking pretty.  How do you adjust the position at that time if that has occurred?

The short answer?  You sold naked $40 calls, you were assigned and now you're short the stock at $40.  The current price is $40.22 so you're down 22 cents.  You did not mention the credit received for the short calls.  If the credit received was greater than 22 cents then your net position is ahead at $40.22.  Is it worth it to sink your teeth into this for another $1 of premium in this  market?  That's your call or in this case, your put :->)

PS My additional two cents is that in this volatile environment, I think that chasing premium is better done with spreads unless your intentional goal is to end up long or short the underlying.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. The premium on my naked call was minimal as the stock price was well below my strike price at the time, so I am currently in a losing position on the trade.

Comment: The first trade didn't go well and walking away with a less than 22 cent loss isn't the end of the world.  In general, I believe that it's not a good idea to contract **Breakevenitis**.

Comment: Yes, I would gladly walk away with only a $0.22 loss.  I attempted to buy back the calls on Thursday, but the premiums were too high and I didn't get filled.  Another responder indicated the CDC extended the no sail order, so maybe the stock retreats on Monday.  After hours trading had the stock at $41.88, That is why I was considering other strategies in case the stock continued to move up.

Comment: Incidentally, I have a bunch of naked Puts at $12.50 expiring in a couple of months and that is why I entered into the naked calls which were way out of the money at the time.  I was trying to reduce my cost base, but I see now that I made a dumb move and took on too much risk for too little gain.  All part of the learning curve I guess.

Comment: Don't wait for options to open at 9:30 AM.  Even 9:30 AM doesn't work because B/A spreads are much wider for much of the first 1/2 hour of trading. If you have approval for pre-market trading and your broker offers it, look to cover the stock early in the pre-market  Monday morning if you want out.  Place your BTC order even if price isn't there.  You never know.

Comment: Under normal circumstances I'd suggest you BTC  your deep OTM $12.50 short puts. It's always a good idea to close long dated short positions for 5-10-15 cents, etc. Given the astronomical IV increase, that can't be done cheaply now. They're not a problem while short  stock, or  until you sell the $60 puts. I'm cautious when it comes to risk so I always look to lay it off. If you cover the short stock and you sold those short puts for fat premium and RCL begins sliding anew, then look to either close the 12.5's or add some negative put delta at a higher strike to offset should the drop continue

Comment: I wish I had access to pre-market trading.  I didn't think my broker offered it, but I will have to check.  Thanks again for the great advice.  I a man so glad I discovered this site today.

Comment: @Hank - FWIW, EliteTrader has an option BB with some rather knowledgeable traders.  Some were former market makers.  The BB members can be a bit arrogant and snippy but that's because it's a mostly unregulated BB.  If you deeper into option trading, your questions may get more complex and you might get some good answers there.

Comment: Thanks Bob. I'll check,out the Elite Trader BB.  Much appreciated!